# Swift - Webview is overlay by navigation bar after implement Javascript

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, wkwebview

I'm implementing JavaScript functions inside my iOS app using swift and it's worked. but the web view size is overlay by the navigation bar. Before I implement Javascript, the web view size is correct. How to fix it?

My reference for this function : https://kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift

```
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

var availabilityWebview: WKWebView?
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController();
    let userScript = WKUserScript(
        source: "redHeader()",
        injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
        forMainFrameOnly: true
    )
    contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "callbackHandler"
    )

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController

    //something wrong here
    self.availabilityWebview = WKWebView(
        frame: self.containerView.bounds,
        configuration: config
    )
    self.view = self.availabilityWebview!
}
```

override func viewWillAppear

```
let url = URL(string: "http://ec2-52-221-231-3.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/gv/available-schedule_3.php?id=\(crewID)")
self.availabilityWebview?.load(URLRequest(url:url!))
```

[image: App Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this code in viewDidLoad

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```